# How to configure a gaming host

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, vmware, gaming

Hi I have a system that has an internet ip address.

I currently have installed debian on the system.

What I would like to do is also install vmware workstation or another virtual management system and setup virtual servers to host some private games on.

for example a quakeworld vm or minecraft vm.

I only have 1 physical nic on the box which just has an internet IP which is accessible through ssh.

What would  be the best method to setup a router in linux so it can route traffic from the internet to the internal virtual nic's on vmware?

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 1 public ip address for multiple machines you would have to set up a NAT router and forward the ports to each host.

I would prefer using the integrated NAT-feature of your virtualization software and set up port forwarding.